# Move file but only if it's closed

Tags: linux, shell-script, monitoring, open-files, lsof

I want to move large file created by external process as soon as it's closed.

Is this test command correct?

```
if lsof "/file/name"
then
        # file is open, don't touch it!
else
        if [ 1 -eq $? ]
        then
                # file is closed
                mv /file/name /other/file/name
        else
                # lsof failed for some other reason
        fi
fi
```

EDIT: the file represents a dataset and I have to wait until it's complete to move it so another program can act on it. That's why I need to know if the external process is done with the file.

Comment: Side note: once a file is opened, processes use file descriptors and inode data to manipulate it. Changing the path (i.e. moving the file) won't cause too much trouble to the process.

Comment: Do you have any control over the external process? Would it be possible for the external process to create a temporary file and rename the file once it's finished writing to it?

Comment: @JennyD I did some investigation and it turns out to be true. I don't need `lsof` at all I just need to check if the file extension is not `.tmp`.  That makes it trivial. However I'm glad I asked my question since I learned a bit about `lsof` and `inotify` and stuff.

Comment: @PeterKovac I learned more about them too, from reading the answers, so I'm very glad you asked it.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith - That's normally true if moving the file within the same filesystem, if he moves the file to a new filesystem before the writer has finished writing to it, he'll lose some data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the `lsof` man page

> Lsof returns a one (1) if any error was detected, including the failure
>          to locate command names, file names, Internet addresses or files, login
>          names, NFS files, PIDs, PGIDs, or UIDs it was asked to list.  If the -V
>          option is specified, lsof will indicate the search items it  failed  to
>          list.

So that would suggest that your `lsof failed for some other reason` clause would never be executed.

Have you tried just moving the file while your external process still has it open? If the destination directory is on the same filesystem, then there should be no problems with doing that unless you need to access it under the original path from a third process as the underlying inode will remain the same. Otherwise I think `mv` will fail anyway.

If you really need to wait until your external process is finished with the file, you are better to use a command that blocks instead of repeatedly polling. On Linux, you can use `inotifywait` for this. Eg:

```
 inotifywait -e close_write /path/to/file
```

If you must use `lsof` (maybe for portability), you could try something like:

```
until err_str=$(lsof /path/to/file 2>&1 >/dev/null); do
  if [ -n "$err_str" ]; then
    # lsof printed an error string, file may or may not be open
    echo "lsof: $err_str" >&2

    # tricky to decide what to do here, you may want to retry a number of times,
    # but for this example just break
    break
  fi

  # lsof returned 1 but didn't print an error string, assume the file is open
  sleep 1
done

if [ -z "$err_str" ]; then
  # file has been closed, move it
  mv /path/to/file /destination/path
fi
```

#### Update

As noted by [@JohnWHSmith](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176387/move-file-but-only-if-its-closed/176392?noredirect=1#comment291450_176392) below, the safest design would always use an `lsof` loop as above as it is possible that more than one process would have the file open for writing (an example case may be a poorly written indexing daemon that opens files with the read/write flag when it should really be read only). `inotifywait` can still be used instead of sleep though, just replace the sleep line with `inotifywait -e close /path/to/file`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `inotify`. Unfortunately, it's not installed on my box but I'm sure I'll find a package somewhere. See my edit for a reason why I need the file to be closed: it's a dataset and it has to be complete before processing it further.

Comment: Another side note: while `inotifywait` will prevent the script from "polling" two often, the OP still needs to check `lsof` in a loop: if the file is opened twice, closing once could trigger the `inotify` event, even though the file isn't ready to be manipulated (for instance, in your last snippet of code, your `sleep` call could be replaced with `inotifywait`).

Comment: @John a `close_write` should be ok since only one process can have the file open for writing at a time. It does assume that another one won't open it straight after it is closed, but then the same issue exists with `lsof` polling.

Comment: @Graeme While this could be true by design in the OP's case, the kernel does allow a file to be opened twice for writing (in which case, `CLOSE_WRITE` is triggered twice).

Comment: @John, updated.

Comment: @Peter, think I am done editing this now. Polling loop should work.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative approach, this is the perfect case for a **[pipe](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Pipes)** - the second process will process output from the first process as soon as it's available, rather than waiting for the full process to finish:

```
process1 input_file.dat | process2 > output_file.dat
```

Advantages:

- Much faster in general:

  - Doesn't have to write to and read from disk (this can be avoided if you use a ramdisk).
  - Should use machine resources more completely.
- No intermediate file to remove after finishing.
- No complex locking necessary, as in OP.

If you have no way of directly creating a pipe but you have **GNU coreutils** you can use this:

```
tail -F -n +0 input_file.dat | process2 > output_file.dat
```

This will start reading the input file from the start, *no matter how far* the first process is through writing the file (even if it's not yet started or already finished).

Comment: Yeah, that would be the "obvious" solution. Unfortunately, the data generating process is out of my control (run by other user).

Comment: @PeterKovac That's irrelevant: *cat input_file.dat | process2  output_file.dat*

Comment: @MariusMatutiae but `cat` and `process2` could finish before `process1` is finished. They wouldn't block.